# How to get the focused element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, element, caret

Using jQuery, how can I get the input element that has the caret's (cursor's) focus?

Or in other words, how to determine if an input has the caret's focus?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967096/using-jquery-to-test-if-an-input-has-focus

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516152/how-to-select-an-element-that-has-focus-on-it-with-jquery/9875020#9875020

Answer (score 822, accepted):

```
// Get the focused element:
var $focused = $(':focus');

// No jQuery:
var focused = document.activeElement;

// Does the element have focus:
var hasFocus = $('foo').is(':focus');

// No jQuery:
elem === elem.ownerDocument.activeElement;
```

Which one should you use? quoting the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/):

> As with other pseudo-class selectors (those that begin with a ":"), it is recommended to precede :focus with a tag name or some other selector; otherwise, the universal selector ("*") is implied. In other words, the bare `$(':focus')` is equivalent to `$('*:focus')`. If you are looking for the currently focused element, $( document.activeElement ) will retrieve it without having to search the whole DOM tree.

The answer is:

```
document.activeElement
```

And if you want a jQuery object wrapping the element:

```
$(document.activeElement)
```

Comment: but wait, how do i get teh element that has the caret?

Comment: @dave. What do you mean _"has the caret"_ ? focused? the mouse is on it?

Comment: well here is my situation:  when i click a particular element, i want to place a character in the last focused input text element.  Basically the element that had focus last or right before clicking that particular element.

Comment: @dave. It can't be done. I think only IE has this feature, but you're asking now a different question, you should do it in a new question.

Comment: @dave in this case you should use `blur` try this `$('input[type="text"]').on('blur', function() {
   // do something here 
})`

Comment: I like how you used $ prefixed variable name, `$focused`, as I assume you do that to denote the var is a jquery object. TYVM.

Comment: OSX typically doesn't give non-text inputs "focus", so document.activeElement generally doesn't work for buttons, radios, etc.

Comment: @SoldOutActivist  that's not the case for Safari, Chrome, or Firefox (at least not currently)    All three browsers correctly return the currently focused button via `document.activeElement`

Answer (score 43):

```
$( document.activeElement )
```

Will retrieve it without having to search the whole DOM tree as recommended on the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/)

Comment: how to get element that has the caret?

Answer (score 6):

I've tested two ways in Firefox, Chrome, IE9 and Safari.

(1). `$(document.activeElement)` works as expected in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

(2). `$(':focus')` works as expected in Firefox and Safari.

I moved into the mouse to input 'name' and pressed Enter on keyboard, then I tried to get the focused element.

(1). `$(document.activeElement)` returns the input:text:name as expected in Firefox, Chrome and Safari, but it returns input:submit:addPassword in IE9

(2). `$(':focus')` returns input:text:name as expected in Firefox and Safari, but nothing in IE

```
<form action="">
    <div id="block-1" class="border">
        <h4>block-1</h4>
        <input type="text" value="enter name here" name="name"/>            
        <input type="button" value="Add name" name="addName"/>
    </div>
    <div id="block-2" class="border">
        <h4>block-2</h4>
        <input type="text" value="enter password here" name="password"/>            
        <input type="submit" value="Add password" name="addPassword"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$(":focus").each(function() {
    alert("Focused Elem_id = "+ this.id );
});
```

Comment: Yes, that's why this loop will have only one iteration. alert is just to demonstrate the example. If you have this variable, you can everything with the element that you want.

Comment: How is it possible to focus more than one element?

Comment: @AndreasFurster you're right. There will always be only one iteration in this loop. This might not be the best way to achieve the goal, but it works.

Comment: See the accepted answer to learn why this is the worst / least efficient way to do it. (unnecessary `.each` non-withstanding)

Answer (score 3):

How is it noone has mentioned..

```
document.activeElement.id
```

I am using IE8, and have not tested it on any other browser. In my case, I am using it to make sure a field is a minimum of 4 characters and focused before acting. Once you enter the 4th number, it triggers. The field has an id of 'year'. I am using..

```
if( $('#year').val().length >= 4 && document.activeElement.id == "year" ) {
    // action here
}
```

Comment: .id will very likely be undefined on multiple elements

Answer (score 1):

`$(':focus')[0]` will give you the actual element.

`$(':focus')` will give you an array of elements, usually only one element is focused at a time so this is only better if you somehow have multiple elements focused.

Answer (score 1):

Try this::

```
$(document).on("click",function(){
    alert(event.target);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to confirm if focus is with an element then

```js
if ($('#inputId').is(':focus')) {
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Yes, another way to do it. It really does depend on which version of JQuery your using :(