# How to tell if nothing is focused?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how I can write a condition for an if-statement in js / jQuery that is when nothing is focused on.

I guess one way one could approach this is everything is blurred ?

I need some help turning this into an if statement where I can put code inside as the suite and then have it executed only if nothing is being focused on currently.

Comment: Bind to the blur event and the focus event. In the blur event, set a timeout, and clear that timeout in the focus event. If the timeout finishes (10ms or so), then nothing is currently focused.

Comment: Please provide a code example of what you're working on.

Comment: something is always focused, even if it is just the window. Only time "everything" is blurred is when you click out of the browser window or change tabs.

Comment: I was wondering what was your actual requirement, there might be a better solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277989/how-to-get-the-focused-element-with-jquery . . . if that is empty, then nothing is focused.  But, I can't imagine that that should ever be the case.  Note the "$(document.activeElement)" answer.

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen I don't have anything right now. I don't know where to start, apologies.

Comment: @ssilas777 what I am actually wondering is when the document / page is focused and nothing within it is focused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('*:focus').length` will return the number of elements that are focused on a page.

- [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A8bca/1/)

To use this in an if statement you can simply check if there is no matching elements and then run whatever code you want.

```
if ($('*:focus').length == 0) {
     //do Something
}
```

**Reference:**

- [.length](http://api.jquery.com/length/)

Comment: `.size()` is deprecated, you should use `.length` instead.

Comment: @Juhana indeed, answer updated.

Comment: Why bind to everything? Why not bind to `document` and let the DOM bubbling make it all come to you?

Comment: @Chad that sounds like a better idea than binding it to everything. How could I fix it because if I replace the * with document, it is in quotes and doesn't refer to the document, but to a <document>, which doesn't exist unless made.

Comment: `$(document)`, which creates a jQuery wrapper around the document object.

Comment: @Chad I know that part, but how do I add the :focus).length part to the $(document) part? Would it be $(document:focus).length?
Apologies if that sounded rude, I didn't mean for it to be.

Comment: @IMUXIxD You misunderstand, never mind; just use this solution for the unfocused count.

Comment: This does not work for textareas. If i focus a textarea it will say evaluate to true

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

it is not a complete solution but without the code you are using posted it is as far as ill go. You can probably figure it out from here.

```
<div id="content">
<input tabIndex="1">
<input tabIndex="2">
<select tabIndex="3">
<option>select menu</option>
</select>
<div tabIndex="4">
a div
</div>
```

> this tests for no inputs focused using the ! operator

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if (!$(':input').is(':focus')){
alert('no focus');
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jvev2/