# What is the jQuery or javaScript syntax to make functions work only on the active/focused input/button/text area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, syntax, webforms

I am a beginner & self interested web coder.

I have been testing, asking, retesting, trying, reading up on different functionality solutions in javaScript to an online form which will consist of a multitude of `<textarea>'s` once I am done.

I am fairly ok, with the current state of functions, which are based upon several js events. Example code would be (*written funny so it is easier to read in the forum, actual code is one line obviously*):

```
<textarea
    data-id="0"
    class="classOne classTwo"
    id="dataInput_0"
    name="xInput_row_1"
        onFocus="functionOne();"
        onBlur="functionTwo();"
        onKeyUp="functionThree();">
</textarea>
```

I built and tested all the functions to work specifically on the `id="dataInput_0"` using `getElementById`. Example:

```
var d = document.getElementById("dataInput_0");
```

So my question is how to I make the functions trigger for other `"dataInput"` id's?

In other words:

```
var d = document.getElementById('whichever dataInput that is active/focused');
```

Thanks!

Comment: _"actual code is one line obviously"_ - Note that there's no problem with formatting your actual code with linebreaks like this.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277989/how-to-get-the-focused-element-with-jquery) what you're asking for?

Comment: @DavidThomas, In the question's title OP mentioned `jQuery` ?

Comment: @Sheikh: ah, yes: I forgot to look at the title for the tags. *tags edited*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to work with your current code would be to do this:

```
onFocus="functionOne(this);"
```

...and then define your function:

```
function functionOne(el) {
   // el is the element in question, used e.g.:
   alert(el.name);
}
```

Within the `onFocus=...` the browser sets `this` to the element in question, so you can then pass it as a parameter to your function. Your function then just uses it directly rather than having to go via `getElementById()`.

But since you mentioned jQuery, you could remove the inline `onFocus` and other `onXYZ` handlers from your html and just do it all in your JS as follows:

```
$("textarea").focus(function() {
   // here this is the element in question, e.g.:
   alert(this.value);
});
```

That defines a focus handler for all textareas on the page - to narrow it down to just textareas with class "classOne" do `$("textarea.classOne")`. Within the function `this` refers to the focused element. You could use the `.blur()` and `keyup()` methods to assign handlers for the other events shown in your code.

Comment: The jQuery solution is working perfectly for the onFocus and onBlur functions, Thanks @nnnnnn!  I believe with a little time, I can work that onKeyUp function to work as well.  Thanks again, and for a patient response.  Thanks also to @Andre & others!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use attribute selector `$('input[id^="dataInput_"]')` for this and use the jQuery's `.on()` handler this way:

```
$('input[id^="dataInput_"]').on({
    focus: function{
       functionOne($(this));
    },
    blur:  function(){
       functionTwo($(this));
    },
    keyup: function(){
       functionThree($(this));
    }
});
```

and the functions:

```
functionOne(obj){
   console.log(obj.val());
}
functionTwo(obj){
   console.log(obj.val());
}
functionThree(obj){
   console.log(obj.val());
}
```

Comment: You might want to double-check the syntax in your `on` statement: it's _calling_ those functions, not assigning them as handlers.

Comment: @nnnnnn & Jai - I have more questions related to this question, and I would like to give more example code. Is it best to just start a new question or edit the original question?

Comment: @Thewannabe-wishhecould - Unless the additional questions are very closely related to the original problem I'd probably start a new question. (But that's just me.)