# How can I find focus element from my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to find which element is focused.For this I tried in the following way.

I have 2 textfields on my web page id's are `field1,field2`

```
var viewObj=Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  events:{
      "blur #field1":"test",
      "blur #field2":"test"
   },
 test:function(){
   console.log(document.activeElement.id);
 }
});
```

what I want,

If you move cursor from `field1` to `field2` prints `field2`

If you move cursor from `field2` to `field1` prints `field1`

If I click anywhere outside,then I want to print something else.

I know `document.activeElement.id`,but it's not working.

can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Comment: If nothing shows up in the console, something is wrong with your events. activeElement works fine in all browsers, so that's not the issue.

Comment: Have you considered using the `onfocus` event?

Comment: Here is given pretty good description
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277989/how-to-get-the-focused-element-with-jquery

Comment: If I use `onfocus` it should work,but I don't want like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use  "document.activeElement" property .

But Tis property only work for thoase field which  accept keystrokes .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery:

```
$("body").focusin(function(event) {
    alert(event.target.id);
});
```

It will alert you an ID of focused element.

http://jsfiddle.net/2Lchy/9/