# Add value to the active input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selecteditem

How can I add value to the active input field among all the `input` fields?

I used `autofocus` attribute to get "the_field" , it didn't return anything.

Comment: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.`

Comment: I am not quite sure how it supposed to behave?

Comment: Have no idea what that sample case is supposed to do. Broken code that doesn't work is not a substitute for  proper problem and expected behavior descriptions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Vanilla JS

First give all the inputs you might want to add stuff to a certain class, lets call it `input-field`. If you are using vanilla JS you can do the JS like this:

```
//Get the focused element.
var focused = document.activeElement;

//Check that it is one of the elements you want to add stuff to.
if(hasClass(focused, 'input-field')) {
    //Add whatever you want to add, lets say a number "3".
    focused.value = focused.value + '3';
}
```

Where `hasClass` is a function that checks if an element has a particular class (stolen from [here](https://gist.github.com/jjmu15/8646098)):

```
hasClass(el, cls) {
    if (!el.className) {
        return false;
    } else {
        var newElementClass = ' ' + el.className + ' ';
        var newClassName = ' ' + cls + ' ';
        return newElementClass.indexOf(newClassName) !== -1;
    }
}
```

Alternatively (as pointed out by Edwin Reynoso), if you are fine with your code not being supported in IE below version 10, you can use [`classList.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList):

```
if(focused.classList.contains('input-field')) {
    ...
```

If you dont want to add the extra class and just check if it is a input with type text you can check for that like this instead:

```
if(focused.tagName == 'input' && focued.getAttribute('type') == 'text') {
    ...
```

## jQuery

Or if you prefer working with JQuery you can do it without an extra function:

```
focused = jQuery(':focus');

if(focused.hasClass('input-field')) {
    focused.val(focused.val() + '3');
}
```

Again, if you want to skip the class and check for an input type text just use this:

```
if(focused.is('input[type=text]')) {
    ...
```

Also see this question: ["How to get the focused element with jQuery?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277989/how-to-get-the-focused-element-with-jquery)

Comment: Please note that this does not respect where in the text field the cursor is, it will simply append to the end. If that is a problem, let me know and I will try to update my answer.

Comment: Ik this is a little old, but do you know that there's `Element.classList.contains()`?? You don't need to implement your own `hasClass()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: Things never get to old for improvement, so thanks - will update my answer. I did not know about it. It is of course much neater, but  the browser support is not so good. You need IE10.