# Adding CSS code to * with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to add this class with jQuery on a click of a button.
I have to add/remove it, can't quite figure out the exact jQuery code for that. Using jQuery 1.12.

**Important note** - 
I have to toggle between the current CSS for the focus status, and the changed CSS (border added). This has to happen **to all of the elements** on the page!

The jQuery code:

```
$("#button").on('click', function() {
//jQuery Code needed to add the class/style.
}
```

CSS code:

```
*:focus {
    border:3px solid black !important;
}
```

Comment: `*` means every element gets a border when focussed.

Comment: You would need to focus onto the element: `$(this).focus();`. If you want to be able to use these styles with a class name just change your declaration to `*:focus, .do-focus {` then you can use `$(this).addClass('do-focus')`

Comment: So "#button" clicked  you want to add border to all the elements?

Comment: Yes, only when the elements are focused! That means I can toggle the focus state of all of the elements on the web page with a button. One time with a border, and one time without.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I used java script to bind the focus event, and used add class/remove class to handle this.

```js
document.addEventListener('focus',function(e){
 var focused = $(':focus');
 focused.addClass('className');
 focused.focusout( function() {
  $(this).removeClass('className');
     });
}, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
$("#button").on('click', function() {
   $('div').addClass('focus'); // or toggleClass
}
```

---

```
.focus { 
  border:3px solid black !important;
}
```

Read more:  [addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/), [removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/), [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Comment: This would be my ideal solution for this context.

Comment: I have to do it to all of my elements on the page, when they are focused.. I was considering using $('*').onfocus()

Comment: try   $('div:focus').addClass('newclass'); // or toggleClass

Comment: also check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277989/how-to-get-the-focused-element-with-jquery

Comment: I don't have the class "element" for all of the tags on the page.. Imagine that I need to overwrite the default behavior of the HTML/CSS for all of the tags, and then bring it back! Now it's buttons, a tags, every focus-able element.

Comment: you should be able to use $('div') tag to access all elements

Answer (score 0):

`.css( propertyName, value )` --> http://api.jquery.com/css/

```
$("#button").on('click', function() {
   $("holdTheItem").css("border", "12px");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would only change the class of the body.

```
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   document.body.classList.toggle('-changedFocus');
});
```

and for the css

```
body.-changedFocus *:focus {
  // your changes
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `*` selector.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shubham_agr10/x0ktLL7j/2/)

Here is the code

```js
$("button").on('click', function() {
var elementCount = $( "#test" ).find( "*" ).css( "border", "3px solid red" ).length;
});
```

```css
h2,
  span,
  p {
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
  }
```

```html
   
<div id="test">
  <h2>H2</h2>
  <span>SPAN</span>
  <p>P</p>
</div>
<button>Button</button>
```

Comment: this is a really bad solution

Comment: It can be wrapped in some div to better performance.I have edited the answer.I know it is not the best solution but I replied according to the question