# Blur event seems to be getting lost if a mousedown event occurring before that delays it

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Here's the code:

```
<input type="text" onblur="myFunction()">
<div style="border: 1px solid; width:300px;height:300px" onmousedown = "myOtherFunction()">


function myOtherFunction(){
  console.log("mousedown on div occurred");
}

function myFunction(){
  console.log("blurr occurred");
}
```

This works as expected if I type in something in the input and clicks on the div, triggering `mousedown` before `blur`. However, if I just put a debugger in `myOtherFunction` and open the developer tool, the `blur` event does not get fired and seems to be lost. Is it perhaps because of the 'delay' which occurs while the debugger is on?

https://jsbin.com/qevapocovo/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: I've tried it on Chrome for Mac and it works as expected: mousedown -> blur. Which browser/OS do you use?

Comment: Same here. Could not reproduce (both events were triggered)

Comment: did you guys try with debuggers on? Just follow the link on the question.
@TasosBu I saw this on Chrome on Mac.

Comment: Yes I can share a screen recording, but I don't know if it follows the TOC of stackoverflow, I'll try in a new comment below

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dq0aB7ISmoxNGTOwomTwSnREuRE2RTDv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Toasos is right. Even I have tried. The mousedown debugger is working first. I have tested the same on mac chrome.

Comment: @TasosBu Oops that's weird. Could it be browser's version issue? See this happening on mine: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qKqYw6KlTq-jqnMHOzURm6hqAzi4Z7_O

Comment: @RahulDwivedi I updated my answer, it works on Safari!

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a debugger issue on Chrome: if you notice [my recording](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dq0aB7ISmoxNGTOwomTwSnREuRE2RTDv/view?usp=sharing) you see that I click the "play" button that appears inside the web app, while in [your recording](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qKqYw6KlTq-jqnMHOzURm6hqAzi4Z7_O) you click the "play" button of the debugger that is inside the developer tools tab. Can you click the in-page "play" that pops when the breakpoint is visited and verify it works as expected?

EDIT:
I created an html file to run directly on Chrome with the same code and the problem persists:

```js
function myOtherFunction(){
  debugger
  console.log("mousedown on div occurred")
  alert("mousedown on div occurred")
}

function myFunction(){
  console.log("blurr occurred")
  alert("blurr occurred")
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onblur="myFunction()">
<div style="border: 1px solid; width:300px;height:300px" onmousedown = "myOtherFunction()"></div>
```

I also tried it on Safari and worked correctly.

Comment: I am using windows, on my browser **mousedown** is occurred before **blurr**. also on my firefox browser **blurr** occurred twice.

Comment: That is how it should work @ZulqarnainJalil see [Events](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) and [Mouse events](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html)

Comment: @Tasos Hmm, that does seem like a debugger issue on chrome. However, I'm still not sure why our `blur` event would just get lost in one case. I mean it must be somewhere in the browser's queue waiting to be executed. How could it simply be discarded?

Comment: Give me some time @RahulDwivedi I need to check the chromium code

Answer (score 0):

Chrome DevTools prevents blur to be fired when debugger is used as it adds an overlay to the page.

See: [Debugging onFocus event using Chrome Developer Tools? Can't return focus after break point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978039/debugging-onfocus-event-using-chrome-developer-tools-cant-return-focus-after-b)

Also, try to not use alert when debugging as it causes issues with focus/blur.